# Mocking when inheriting from pyserial

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have a class that inherits from `pyserial`'s `serial.Serial` class that looks something like this:

```
class SYM1(serial.Serial):
    def __init__(self, *args, debug=None, baudrate=4800, timeout=1, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
        LOG.info('using port %s', self.port)

    def read(self, count):
        ...
        return super().read(count)

    def write(self, data):
        ...
        return super().write(data)

    def connect(self):
        ...

    def send_command(self, cmd, *args):
        ...
```

I would like to write unit tests for the class, but I'm unsure how best to set things up such that (a) methods defined on the `SYM1` class are callable normally, while (b) methods inherited from `serial.Serial` are mocked out.

I started with this:

```
import pytest
import serial

from unittest import mock


serial.Serial = mock.MagicMock
from symtool import symtool  # NOQA


@pytest.fixture
def sym(monkeypatch):
    s = symtool.SYM1('TESTDEV')
    s.connect()
    return s


def test_connect(sym):
    pass
```

But that fails here:

```
LOG.info('using port %s', self.port)
```

With:

```
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'port'
```

and that puzzles me, because if it's a `mock.Mock` object, I would expect:

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> m = mock.Mock()
>>> m.port
<Mock name='mock.port' id='139910315631568'>
```

It's not just simple attributes; if I comment out the line causing the first `AttributeError`, it will instead fail later on when calling `super().write`:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'write'
```

What's going on here, and what's the right way to do it?

Comment: Consider not using inheritance at all, but composition. `SYM1.__init__` will take an instance of `Serial` in production, but an instance of some dummy class in your tests. All your `SYM1` methods will use that object rather than overriding inherited methods.

Comment: The problem is that I am overriding the `read` and `write` methods, which are called by other methods of the `Serial` class. I don't think there's a graceful way to do this via composition.

Comment: `def read(self, count): return self.serial_obj.read(count)`.  The caller doesn't know if you are using `super` or delegating to another object.

Comment: No, the problem is that when a method in `serial.Serial` calls e.g. `read`. So the `SYM1` calls `self.read_until(...)`, and the `read_until` method, which is defined on `serial.Serial` *not* on `SYM1`, calls `self.read`. This won't work if we're calling `self.serial_obj.read_until`.